# visual C++ declaring a string array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like to use unmanaged C++.

The following code:

```
#include"string.h"
std::string nodename[100];
```

Gives me the following compilation error:

> 'std' : is not a class or namespace
>   name

Answer (score 15):

You're using the wrong header file.  You should be `#include`ing `<string>`, not `"string.h"`:

- `<string>` is the header file that defines the C++ STL class `std::string`
- `<string.h>` is the header file for the C standard library of string functions, which operate on C strings (`char *`)
- `<cstring>` is the header file like `<string.h>`, but it declares all of the C string functions inside of the `std` namespace

For system header files like these, you should always `#include` them with angle brackets, not with double quotes.

Comment: Using quotes `""` gives precedence to the files in your own project that happen to have the same name. Angle brackets `<>` do the opposite.

Answer (score 9):

Try something like:

```
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::string nodeName[100];
}
```

It's just `string`, not `string.h`.